# AOT compile error via angular-cli, conflict with HTML attribute data-on-color

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I ran this cmd `ng build --prod`, but I got this error `Property 'brand' does not exist on type`.

No idea why does data-on-color="brand" HTML attribute related to this.

I have tried to rename all `data-on-color="brand"` to something else. Eg. `data-lon-color="brand"` and then AOT compilation is working.

[image: error image]

Below is the content of file `/theme/angular/default/src/app/theme/pages/components/base/base-bootstrap-notify/base-bootstrap-notify.component.html`, as stated in the error.

```html
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                URL Clickable
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <input data-switch="true" type="checkbox" data-on-color="brand"  id="m_notify_url">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                Allow dismiss
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <input data-switch="true" type="checkbox" checked data-on-color="brand"  id="m_notify_dismiss">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                Pause on hover
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <input data-switch="true" type="checkbox" data-on-color="brand" id="m_notify_pause">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Below is the .ts file `BaseBootstrapNotifyComponent`

```typescript
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {ScriptLoaderService} from '../../../../../_services/script-loader.service';


@Component({
    selector: "app-base-bootstrap-notify",
    templateUrl: "./base-bootstrap-notify.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./base-bootstrap-notify.component.scss"],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class BaseBootstrapNotifyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _script: ScriptLoaderService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this._script.load('app-base-bootstrap-notify',
            'assets/demo/default/custom/components/base/bootstrap-notify.js');

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular [normalizes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L428-L432) attribute name when parses template

```typescript
private _normalizeAttributeName(attrName: string): string {
  return /^data-/i.test(attrName) ? attrName.substring(5) : attrName;
}
```

So your string becames

```html
<input on-color="brand">
```

*Note:* even `<div data-*ngIf="3">Hello</div>` will work without problem.

Then angular has two options to declare events

1) `(event)`

2) `on-event`

Therefore angular thinks that you declared Output event with `color` name

```html
<input (color)="brand">
```

and for aot you have to declare handler `brand` within your component.

Workaround

```html
<input [attr.data-on-color]="'brand'">
```

Comment: Can I just use single quote like this? seems the error is gone now.
`<input data-switch="true" type="checkbox" data-on-color="'brand'"  id="m_notify_url">`

Comment: Do you see `data-on-color` attribute on your input  after that? I think you don't. But yes, the error should gone in this case because angular compiler won't search for brand string. It's the same as `(color)="'brand'" `